# GET route of path "/login" does not work with guest middleware and Auth facade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm not using Laravel's authentication system in my app. Instead, I created my own one wrapped around the following routes:

```
Route::get('login', array(
    'middleware' => 'guest',
    'uses' => 'UserController@showLogin'
));

Route::post('login', array(
    'uses' => 'UserController@login'
));
```

The login form (`POST`) works and the user gets redirected after successful `Auth::attempt()`. However, when the user tries to access **/login** again (`GET`) the page is displayed even if the `guest` middleware is applied to it. In addition, `Auth::check()` returns `false`...

I figured out that if I change the `get` route from `Route::get('login')` to `Route::get('anything-else')` - the `guest` middleware suddenly works.

I assume this has something to do with how Laravel handles authentication out of the box, and that the **/login** path is somehow "special". I find it ridiculous. How else would I name the page on which I provide login functionality?

**Does anyone know if there's any config I could use to wipe out Laravel's native auth system from my app?**

As I wrote, I'm using custom one and I would really like to get back the freedom of naming my routes however I please without losing basic functionality.

Comment: So, do you have middleware "wrapped around the following routes"? If so, that's the issue. The `guest` middleware should not be inside other authentication middleware.

Comment: The `guest` middleware comes with Laravel. Using it on anything else than `Route::get('login')` works just fine. Problem is that my auth system (meaning, my routes) is colliding with Laravel's probably. Or, rather, Laravel's collides with mine. I would like to know how to tell Laravel: GTFO with your auth implementation, forget it ;)

Comment: Is there any controller middleware in `UserController`?

Comment: @DavidBarker No there's not. `UserController` is very simple - show login page, log user in and redirect, logout.

Comment: Laravel does not collide with custom authentication if you don't tell it to. You need to make sure your `login` route is attached to `guest` middleware only. Everything else should have `auth` middleware.